# Is there any magic command to not run a specific cell in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I'm doing an assignment for my university and in my notebook I'm running the following model. My question is if there is a way to tell python not to run a specific cell when my teacher tries to run all cells.

```
# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

# Fit the model
epochs = 50
history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_ds)
```

Comment: Comment it out?

Comment: `%%script false --no-raise-error`